# Installed Lubuntu alogside with Windows XP but unable to boot

Tags: 14.04, boot, lubuntu

I have installed Lubuntu on IBM Thinkpad T40 alongside with Windows XP . The boot menu appears but my Lubuntu unable to boot.

Comment: what do you see when tries to boot?

Comment: If possible get us a screenshot or any error message that pops up? If not describe the screen, so we get a better picture of the issue.

Comment: no error msg just black screen . I have solved the problem by reinstalling it again without XP. Everything is good but i have no sound. any suggestions

Comment: Adil, Could you answer your own question first, detailing *how* you did it exactly and then ask a new question?  AskUbuntu is a bit different from other sites, it's a wiki, forum, blog and support site all in one.  (http://stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: I erased the disk and only installed lubuntu with force pae and it worked